# SharePoint 2010 REST filter by current user

Tags: rest, sharepoint-2010

Using REST in SharePoint 2010, how do you select / filter rows of a list which belong to the user currently logged in (whether it's a case of filtering by Author, Editor, or by a Person field)

e.g.

```
http://myserver/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/Test?$filter=Author eq Me
```

I know in SP2007, using caml you can use the UserID element which represents the value of the current user.

EDIT:
Humm, seems the Author, Editor and any other Person field are stored as Ints and are renamed to CreatedById and ModifiedById. If you query a list all you get back is

```
<d:CreatedById m:type="Edm.Int32">1</d:CreatedById>
```

What if I want to get back the NT name of the user? Do I have to do another query somewhere to get the Int value for a certain user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see

`http://spdevportal/dev/Lab2/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/IPParams?$expand=CreatedBy`

and use

`http://spdevportal/dev/Lab2/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/IPParams?$filter=CreatedBy/Account eq 'OFFICE\alexandr.pletnev'`

Answer (score 5):

You can also use this with UserID. 
Retrieve UserId by using  code:

`var userId = _spPageContextInfo.userId;`

and use it in URL as below:

```
"http://spdevportal/dev/Lab2/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/IPParams?$filter=CreatedById eq"+userId
```

Ex:  `http://spdevportal/dev/Lab2/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/IPParams?$filter=CreatedById eq 213`

It will give you all the items created by Currently LoggedIn user.

You can also add some additional filter using 'and'

```
"http://spdevportal/dev/Lab2/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/IPParams?$filter=CreatedById eq"+userId+" and StatusValue eq 'approved'"
```

Ex:

```
"http://spdevportal/dev/Lab2/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/IPParams?$filter=CreatedById eq 213 and  StatusValue eq 'approved'"
```